# Using C names in C++

Tags: c++, c

I have to make C function names visible in a development environment (Keil uVision) from within a C++ application. Unfortunatly the names being displayed still use the C++ name mangling. So instead of displaying `Task1` the system displays `_Z5Task1Pv`.

In C++ I call

```
{
...
threadDef->pthread = (void (*)(void const*))getTaskID(tfunc);
...
threadId = osThreadCreate(threadDef, param);
}
```

then in a C file I have

```
extern "C" {
    ...
    typedef void (*TaskFct)(void*);
    ...
    static void Task1(void* param) { ... }
    ...
    static TaskFct getTaskID(TaskFct tFunc) {
    ...
    return Task1;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get the pure C names in a C++ application?

Comment: What is this `(\*)`?

Comment: If you have `extern "C"` in a C file, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm going to guess the OP noticed that `\*` can be used to avoid making text bold in Markdown, and only then noticed to indent it to get it to show up as code where escaping is no longer necessary.

Comment: if the functions are exported from shared object written in c, then they shouldn't be mangled. You should use extern "C" to prevent C++ mangling the names it exports

Comment: it would be helpful to know what your source file names are (esp. the extension). You might have C++ file renamed to a .c file

Comment: @Jimmy: Why do you assume that file extension have **any** meaning at all? They don't. You can pass a file with a file extension *pileofpoo* to any C++ compiler. Apart from that, using `extern "C"` doesn't magically remove name mangling. It merely tells the compiler to use C name mangling instead of C++ name mangling.

Comment: Your `extern "C" {}` statement should be visible to the C++ compiler in the source file where you call your C routines, before the calls.

Comment: @IInspectable You are wrong. GCC pays attention to the extension. [Pass `file.cpp` to `gcc` and it'll be compiled as C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6560197b8d446113) (although you will have to link in the C++ standard library implementation yourself to get the result past the linker). Furthermore, C doesn't have name mangling.

Comment: @Lightness: Then again, GCC is not a C++ compiler. G++ would be your compiler driver for the C++ compiler. *"Furthermore, C doesn't have name mangling."* - That depends on the compiler you use. Microsoft's compilers have always used [Name Decoration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx) for C as well.

Comment: @IInspectable: Right, that's exactly my point. Despite invoking `gcc` rather than `g++` (and both are part of the software called "GCC"), the executable has spotted the extension `.cpp` and passed the code through the C++ front-end instead of the C front-end. So your confident statement that the extension has no meaning at all is absolute nonsense.

Comment: @Lightness: A file extension has absolutely **zero** meaning at all, unless you pass a file to a selector app whose sole purpose is to launch another application based on the file extension. Well, d'uh...

Comment: - extern "C" is written because this part is included in the C++ application

Comment: @IInspectable I'm with lightness on this one - pretty much every compiler I've used treats .c and .cpp differently - whether this is the cause of the OP's problem is another matter

Comment: - I have to use the Keil / ARM C++ compiler, so unfortunatly gnu is not an option

Comment: @IInspectable: Right, so a file extension has absolutely **zero** meaning at all, except when it doesn't. Glad we got that cleared up!

Comment: @Lightness: The file extension doesn't carry intrinsic meaning. It's the application that evaluates it, that induces meaning (when it really shouldn't). If the file extension were meaningful, it wouldn't be possible to compile a stream, that doesn't have a file name at all. At any rate, if your time is useless, you get the last word on this. Mine isn't and this is it from my end.

Comment: @IInspectable The thing is, you were saying or strongly implying that the file extension would be ignored by whatever compiler the OP is using. LRIO rightly gave an example of a real commonly-used compiler front-end that doesn't ignore the file extension. If that doesn't invalidate whatever point you were trying to make, you need to explain yourself a lot more clearly, because I have no clue whatsoever what else you might've meant by your comment.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, `extern "C" {...}` is used by a c++ compiler to prevent name mangling (or at least c++ name mangling).  I currently have a setup where I have a userspace "driver" written in c and a handful of c++ apps that statically link it in.  I use gcc to build the `MyCDriver.o` file, then g++ to build the `cpp` apps and link in the driver.  At the top of each `cpp` class where I want to call driver functions I have

```
 extern "C"
 {
   #include "MyCDriverHeader.h"
 }
```

Then to compile the `cpp` apps:

```
 g++ -o MyCppApp MyCppApp.cpp MyCDriver.o
```

Comment: The typical pattern here is to have that `extern "C"` straight into the header, enclosed in `#ifdef __cplusplus`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia that's correct, however, I don't like that paradigm. I keep my `c` and `c++` code separate. `c` has no notion of `c++`, nor should it. If `c++` wants to use `c` code, then the burden of inclusion/compatibility should be left to the `c++` code. What if some cool new `c+2` language comes out 10 years from now,, should I start adding `#ifdef __cplustwo` guards to my `c` code now just to be ready? Furthermore, I can look at my `#include`s in my `c++` code and immediately know what's `c++` and what's `c` based on the `extern "C"` w/o opening header files.. my minority opinion anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Like this in the header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```